# Is there any way to accomplish h4 + p but change the h4 with css or scss

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Say I have an h4

```css
h4 {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

// somehow select h4's that are immediately followed by p tags
h4 + p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

My hope was to change the bottom margin if a paragraph tag followed it rather then any other tag.

Is there any efficient way to do this with css or scss?

> If not I plan to just rewrite the typography using top margin except for the first element. I would like to avoid the rewrite if possible.

Comment: Read about the `has` selector, but sadly there's no support for it yet
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has
For your example would have been `h4:has(+ p) {}`